# Final URL when using `withFollowRequests`

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Using the [Play WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS), and following a simple example from the documentation:

```
WS.url(url).withFollowRedirects(true).get().map { response =>
   ...
}
```

is there any way to recover, from `response` or elsewhere, the final URL that was reached after following all redirections?

Comment: You may try and get the `Location` header from the response, but I'm not sure it's requried.

Comment: My understanding of the `Location` header is that it is be set for the intermediary response(s), to trigger the redirections, but not for the final one.

Comment: (And it is indeed not set in my usecase, I should add)